# PHP: To implement API or WebService to transfer simple data?

Tags: php, web-services, api

I'm a bit confused about `API vs WebService`. But anyway, which one will you follow to.. lets say to provide simple string or xml or json data return.

Currently i have implemented something like:

Server:

```
echo json_encode("hello, ".$_POST["q"]);
```

Client:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $server_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('q' => 'world!'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

- Normally as the standard way, how do we even call/name it? Shall i name it `API`? Or `WebService`?
- And in normal way (whenever we need to provide some data out of Server, like above) which one do we implement?

Comment: Please provide the difference in terms `webservice` and `api`

Comment: what is the difference between `webservice` and `api`?

Comment: have you read the correspondent wikipedia articles?